# Compare timespan to integer

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

Is it possible to compare a timespan to an integer in C#?

if say I want to know if a timespan is equal to 30 days, and if it is then do something?

Comment: You should try to press F1 or use intelissense some time : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is 30 days and 1 tick essentially equal to 30 days?

Answer (score 3):

There is the property [TotalDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx)

There's also `TotalHours`, `TotalMinutes`, `TotalSeconds` and `TotalMilliseconds`. You should check out the [TimeSpan-properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) for more information

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property `Days` of the `TimeSpan` object, which returns the days component of the time interval

```
if (ts.Days == 30)
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: be careful, there is a difference between `Days` and `TotalDays`

Comment: @peter, yes but still 1 and 1.xx will give the same result when compare to int.

Comment: Yes, my answer was based on the assumption that the user wanted to compare to an integer, so just whole days and not fractions

Comment: 30 days 23 hours 59 minutes still gives `Days = 30`, but `TotalDays = 30.999xxx`, so there **is** a significant difference.

Comment: It *might* be a dupe, I'm still not convinced the OP want's to discard the time on that 30th day and just say "30 ish". It is a big difference between "exactly 30 days" and "30 days and some extra time".

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan();
if(t.TotalDays==30)
{
//Do Something
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code and how it solves the OP's question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)

Comment: found the right solution for me thanks for the help